# Error in getting API data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, api, server

I use JavaScript to get the API data from https://aparat.com and I get 'Cross-Origin Request Blocked' error every time. The method I use works for other sites but not for this site and the API file is text and is not json file. Could you please to help me what should i do? Thank you

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    return response.json();
}

postData('https://www.aparat.com/etc/api/video/videohash/Pua5e', '').then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Do you have to use Javascript?  Can you use `wp_remote_get` function?

Comment: Hi @howard-e thank you for replay. Yes is has to be Javascript. I'm not sure could i use it or combination it with Javascript!

Comment: To identify the issue, you could follow those [guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors#identifying_the_issue)

Comment: Aparat doesn't have a public API from what I can see so sending it a POST request doesn't make sense to me. You could do a GET request _maybe_, but it might still block you due to CORS. If you can link me to any documentation, that would help more.

Comment: @hamza765 This link is Aparat API documentation: https://www.aparat.com/api